# Differentiability at $0$ of $(\sum_1^n \lvert x_i\rvert^p)^{1/q}$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Find all $p,q>0$ for which function $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R,$ $f(x)=(\sum_1^n \lvert x_i\rvert^p)^{1/q}$ is differentiable at $(0,\dots,0).$

I know that $p$ has to be bigger than $q$ for the existence of partial derivatives.

I wanted to take linear transformation which jacobian matrix is $(0,\dots,0)$ and compute the total derivative from definition but I guess I can't compute this limit.

Comment: Your last sentence (beginning with "I wanted") is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: For a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $p > 0$, set $\Vert x \Vert_p = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$. Then $f(x) = \Vert x \Vert_p^{p/q}$. You want to show
$$
    \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\Vert x \Vert_p^{p/q}}{\Vert x \Vert_2}=0
$$
Suppose there exist constants $c$ and $C$ such that for all $x$,
$$
    c \Vert x \Vert_2 \leq \Vert x \Vert_p \leq C \Vert x \Vert_2
$$
Then we would have
$$
    c \Vert x \Vert_p^{p/q-1} \leq \frac{\Vert x \Vert_p^{p/q}}{\Vert x \Vert_2} \leq C \Vert x \Vert_p^{p/q-1}
$$

Can you take it from there? Can you find a suitable $c$ and $C$?